# Cloudfoundry Deploy - java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

Tags: java, web-services, soap, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I have a [spring boot app](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/soap/tree/master/soap-server) which is basically a soap server and publishing a web service.

When I am running the app on local it's publishing the wsdl at - http://localhost:9999/service/hello-world?wsdl, and as soon as I try to push it on Local `Cloudfoundry`, it fails at time of starting the app stating the reason:

> Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied

**manifest.yml** of the app looks like:

```
---
applications:
- name: soap-server
  memory: 1G
  random-route: true
  path: target/soap-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

And modified `SoapServerApplication` for Local `Cloudfoundry` deployment looks like:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SoapServerApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        Endpoint.publish("http://soap-server.local.pcfdev.io"+ "/service/hello-world", new HelloWorldServiceImpl());
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SoapServerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Complete logs:**

```
App instance exited with guid 7c476beb-6e16-4a25-bed3-51ce289a8180 payload: {"instance"=>"", "index"=>0, "reason"=>"CRASHED", "exit_description"=>"2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* 2 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Exited with status 1\n* cancelled\n* cancelled", "crash_count"=>5, "crash_timestamp"=>1481326885385909754, "version"=>"dd0fa534-cc5b-4012-acff-3a23c390987c"}
Successfully destroyed container
Creating container
Successfully created container
Starting health monitoring of container
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.3.6.RELEASE)
2016-12-09 23:43:49.229  INFO 17 --- [           main] pertySourceApplicationContextInitializer : Adding 'cloud' PropertySource to ApplicationContext
2016-12-09 23:43:49.394  INFO 17 --- [           main] nfigurationApplicationContextInitializer : Adding cloud service auto-reconfiguration to ApplicationContext
2016-12-09 23:43:49.427  INFO 17 --- [           main] c.a.s.server.main.SoapServerApplication  : Starting SoapServerApplication on 3le7g13378f with PID 17 (/home/vcap/app started by vcap in /home/vcap/app)
2016-12-09 23:43:49.430  INFO 17 --- [           main] c.a.s.server.main.SoapServerApplication  : The following profiles are active: cloud
2016-12-09 23:43:49.541  INFO 17 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1f17ae12: startup date [Fri Dec 09 23:43:49 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-09 23:43:51.384  INFO 17 --- [           main] urceCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type javax.sql.DataSource
2016-12-09 23:43:51.386  INFO 17 --- [           main] edisCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisConnectionFactory
2016-12-09 23:43:51.385  INFO 17 --- [           main] ongoCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory
2016-12-09 23:43:51.385  INFO 17 --- [           main] bbitCloudServiceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Skipping auto-reconfiguring beans of type org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactory
2016-12-09 23:43:52.179  INFO 17 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2016-12-09 23:43:52.213  INFO 17 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service Tomcat
2016-12-09 23:43:52.218  INFO 17 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.36
2016-12-09 23:43:52.417  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2016-12-09 23:43:52.419  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2881 ms
2016-12-09 23:43:53.003  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.013  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.014  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.014  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.015  INFO 17 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.467  INFO 17 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter : Looking for @ControllerAdvice: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1f17ae12: startup date [Fri Dec 09 23:43:49 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-09 23:43:53.584  INFO 17 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error],produces=[text/html]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse)
2016-12-09 23:43:53.596  INFO 17 --- [           main] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Mapped "{[/error]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>> org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.error(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
2016-12-09 23:43:53.649  INFO 17 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.649  INFO 17 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/webjars/**] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.706  INFO 17 --- [           main] o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapped URL path [/**/favicon.ico] onto handler of type [class org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler]
2016-12-09 23:43:53.886  INFO 17 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2016-12-09 23:43:54.041  INFO 17 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
Container became healthy
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
2016-12-09 23:43:54.550 ERROR 17 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    at com.arpit.soap.server.main.SoapServerApplication.main(SoapServerApplication.java:24) [app/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54) [app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:104) [app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61) [app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52) [app/:na]
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:117) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(HttpEndpoint.java:64) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:232) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:126) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.arpit.soap.server.main.SoapServerApplication.run(SoapServerApplication.java:20) [app/:na]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800) [spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.6.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:130) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:86) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    ... 20 common frames omitted
2016-12-09 23:43:54.564  INFO 17 --- [           main] .b.l.ClasspathLoggingApplicationListener : Application failed to start with classpath: [file:/home/vcap/app/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-expression-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-webmvc-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-context-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-core-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/jboss-logging-3.3.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-aop-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/jackson-annotations-2.6.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-starter-web-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-cloud-spring-service-connector-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/tomcat-embed-el-8.0.36.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/jul-to-slf4j-1.7.21.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/classmate-1.1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-web-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-cloud-core-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-beans-4.2.7.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/logback-core-1.1.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-starter-tomcat-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/logback-classic-1.1.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring_auto_reconfiguration-1.10.0_RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-starter-logging-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/snakeyaml-1.16.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/jcl-over-slf4j-1.7.21.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/tomcat-embed-logging-juli-8.0.36.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/jackson-databind-2.6.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/tomcat-embed-core-8.0.36.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-starter-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.21.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/jackson-core-2.6.7.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/spring-boot-starter-validation-1.3.6.RELEASE.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/aopalliance-1.0.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/tomcat-embed-websocket-8.0.36.jar!/, jar:file:/home/vcap/app/lib/hibernate-validator-5.2.4.Final.jar!/]
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report enable debug logging (start with --debug)
2016-12-09 23:43:54.571  INFO 17 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 
2016-12-09 23:43:54.571  INFO 17 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@1f17ae12: startup date [Fri Dec 09 23:43:49 UTC 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-12-09 23:43:54.583  INFO 17 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:61)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:104)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:803)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:784)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:54)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1174)
    at com.arpit.soap.server.main.SoapServerApplication.main(SoapServerApplication.java:24)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: com.sun.xml.internal.ws.server.ServerRtException: Server Runtime Error: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:117)
    at com.arpit.soap.server.main.SoapServerApplication.run(SoapServerApplication.java:20)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:800)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.HttpEndpoint.publish(HttpEndpoint.java:64)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.EndpointImpl.publish(EndpointImpl.java:232)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.spi.ProviderImpl.createAndPublishEndpoint(ProviderImpl.java:126)
    at javax.xml.ws.Endpoint.publish(Endpoint.java:240)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:433)
    at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Net.java:425)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:223)
    at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:74)
    at sun.net.httpserver.ServerImpl.<init>(ServerImpl.java:100)
    at sun.net.httpserver.HttpServerImpl.<init>(HttpServerImpl.java:50)
    at sun.net.httpserver.DefaultHttpServerProvider.createHttpServer(DefaultHttpServerProvider.java:35)
    at com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer.create(HttpServer.java:130)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.server.ServerMgr.createContext(ServerMgr.java:86)
    ... 20 more
Exit status 1
Exit status 0
```

Any idea how can I fix it?

Comment: Tomcat seems to be starting on port 8080.  Where is the port set for your SoapServer?  Are you certain it will be on 9999?  `SocketException: Permission denied` sounds like it's either trying to listen on 8080, which is already in use, or it's trying to listen on a port less than 1024 which would require root permissions to do.

Comment: @DanielMikusa port is set in `application.properties` and it is 9000 as one can see - https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/soap/blob/master/soap-server/src/main/resources/application.properties. Any idea why it's not picking up 9000? On local deployment server is starting at 9000.

Comment: `server.port` is going to be overridden by the Java build pack.  It will set `server.port` to the port provided by CF (i.e. $PORT).  It does this with a command line arg, so it takes precedence over what's in `application.properties`.  Look at the start command generated for your app.  99% of the time this is the correct action and what you want.  Why are you trying to set it to 9000?

Comment: @DanielMikusa You are correct `server.port` is overridden by Java build pack. Any idea how can I start my server on port other than `8080`($PORT)? And answer to your question - I am setting the port 9000 because I want to start the server on port other than `8080` and `9000` is the first number came to my mind.

Comment: You must use $PORT.  The platform expects your application to be listening on this port.  If it's not then the platform's port health check will fail and your app will be deemed to have crashed.  Beyond that, the gorouters could never send traffic to your app because they would not know how to contact it.  In short, you must use the assigned port.  Does your app work if you use the assigned port?

Comment: @DanielMikusa no it's not working, what I understood is happening, my app is starting at `8080` and main class try to publish webservice at same port, so I am getting `Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Permission denied`, what I am thinking if I change the port from assigned port to some other port and let my webservice to publish at `8080`. Do you suggest any solution how can I make it work?

Comment: You can't listen on two ports with one CF app.  There's only one inbound port assigned to an app instance.  All incoming requests are sent to that port.  Thus you can have Tomcat listen on the port and serve up a web app or you can have your web service listen but you *can't* do both.  Can you integrate the service into Tomcat, so that Tomcat is listening on the assigned port and just delegating to the web service?

Comment: @DanielMikusa I got your point, `Can you integrate the service into Tomcat, so that Tomcat is listening on the assigned port and just delegating to the web service?` - if this is the case I have to change the  current implementation, let me see what's the easiest way to do it. Thanks.